# How to pass link to Read More manually

Tags: 7, nodes

I enabled the blog module and I created the blog called test blog. I created the template file as `page--blog.tpl.php`. Here is my code:

```
   <!--ip_mainLeft starts here-->
    <div class="ip_mainLeft">

        <h1 class="ipMainHeading">News</h1>
         <?php 
        $type = "blog";
        $nodes = node_load_multiple(array(), array('type' => $type));
        foreach($nodes as $news):
        ?>  
        <!--newsEnclose starts here-->
        <div class="newsEnclose">

            <!--newsDateInfo starts here-->
            <div class="newsDateInfo">

                <span class="news_date"><?php print date( "j",$news->created); ?></span>
                <span class="news_month"><?php print date( "M Y",$news->created); ?></span>

            </div>
            <!--newsDateInfo ends here-->

            <!--newsText starts here-->
            <div class="newsText">

                <h1 class="newsTextHeading"><a href="<?php print $node->nid; ?>">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></h1>
                <p><?php $body = field_get_items('node', $news, 'body');
                        $teaser= $body[0]['safe_summary'];
                        print $teaser; ?></p>

                <a href="javascript:;" class="ip_readMore">+ Read More</a>

            </div>
            <!--newsText ends here-->

        </div>
        <!--newsEnclose ends here-->
```

If the heading or ReadMore button is clicked. I want to display full blog content of particular node in the blog content type. How to pass the link in anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

missed value in `href`.  replace below code.

```
<h1 class="newsTextHeading"><a href="/node/<?php print $node->nid; ?>">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</a></h1>
```

Comment: `page.tpl.php` if the page is not front.